# Cleaning up email distribution list of bad/invalid emails

Tags: email, coldfusion, gmail

We have a newsletter where people opt-in (everything is on the up and up here). As people leave jobs (fired, layoffs, etc.), we still send to those emails and now after a few years, we have a considerable amount of emails that need to be purged.

The inbox that is receiving the bounces/invalid emails is a gmail account. We can filter (via a search) and find the emails that need to be removed but how can we export those emails to a list so that we can clean up our distribution list? Are there any tools that would help simply this?

We are looking into mailgun and sendgrid for future send outs but we need to clean up the list before we migrate. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Our tech stack is apache/coldfusion 11 (not that it matters but in case it helps).

Comment: I thought about setting up a gmail rule that would forward bounces to another gmail account and then exporting the data from there but I suspect there is an easier, more automated way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Do you have any info on 1.) how you are using ColdFusion AND 2.) The strategy that you are currently using.

Comment: ColdFusion is simply used to send out the emails. It doesn't have anything to do with bounced item. I included the CF referenced since there are APIs and CFC (riaforge for example) and thought it might appeal to a broader support scope to arrive at a solution. :).  I don't have a strategy yet. I need help there as well. Right now I am going into the gmail account copying the email, and deleting from the database (via a form, not directly from the database). The solution doesn't need to be elegant since it is short term until we migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CF to log into gmail and pull all the messages. Then loop through them all to find the bounce messages. Appending those bounced email addressed to a simple flat file. If you want to get fancy you can use a database, but I think a simple text file would do in this case. One email address per line.

I just read that you are deleting those bounced email addresses from a database. IF you're confident of your coding the above idea, you could directly delete from your database rather than saving a file.

Comment: This is essentially exactly what we want to do but hoping we do not have to recreate the wheel. We'd like to use an existing ColdFusion CFC and/or Google's API but the CFC's we have found are out of date.

Comment: If you want your wheelbarrow to roll, you'll need the wheel. =) It shouldn't be too much of a function to write. Use cfpop giving it a name, which you then use a query. Loop through that query deciding whether or not it's a bounce and update your database accordingly. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpop.html

Comment: Agreed, if you searched and did not turn up anything, there probably is not anything pre-made for this exact task (guessing most folks are probably using something other than CF for mailing). If the bounced messages are going to a separate mailbox, the suggestion above is a simple solution. Though personally I would NOT do direct updates. Easy enough to bulk a insert text file into a temporary table and use JOINs to review/clean up the existing list.

Comment: Admittedly, I was looking for an imap solution but cfpop may work just as well for this short term tasks. And yes @Leigh definitely not direct updates. A CSV file for sure! Thanks for looking out for me! :)

Comment: @HPWD - Not sure if cfimap has any "quirks". Might give it a whirl for grins. Though like you said, for a one time task like this, cfpop would probably do the trick :)